# Fill string with values from names given in tags

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working in java, I am not able to find help regarding populating String with tags, for example, I have the following string

```
Dear Mr {{person_name}}, Your current status is {{current_status}}.
```

I want to make string at run time like below

```
Dear Mr Pitter, Your current status is active.
```

I am working in spring boot.

Comment: Can you share, what you've already tried? Probably `String.format` would work for you.

Comment: String.format("Dear Mr %s, Your current status is %s.", person_name, current_status);

Comment: I tried String.format but it does not fulfill my requirement Sir. I have also tried String.format it only working with %s.    StringTemplate st = new StringTemplate("Dear Mr $person_name$, Your current status is $current_status$.");
        st.setAttribute("person_name","Pitter");
        st.setAttribute("current_status","active");
        st.toString();

Comment: show the code that helps us to workout on it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example using `org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate` since you mentioned trying that yourself. It works by replacing every instance of `{{` and `}}` with `$`

```
package com.demo.template;

import org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.DefaultTemplateLexer;

public class StringTemplatePoc {

    public String stringsForTags(String personName, String currentStatus) {
        StringTemplate stringForTags =
                new StringTemplate(
                        "Dear Mr {{person_name}}, Your current status is {{current_status}}."
                        .replaceAll("(\\{\\{|}})", "\\$"),
                        DefaultTemplateLexer.class);
        stringForTags.setAttribute("person_name", personName);
        stringForTags.setAttribute("current_status", currentStatus);
        return stringForTags.toString();
    }
}
```

And a test that runs successfully

```
package com.demo.template;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class StringTemplatePocTest {

    private final StringTemplatePoc poc = new StringTemplatePoc();

    @Test
    public void stringsForTagsShouldReplacePersonNameAndStatus() {
        assertThat(poc.stringsForTags("Pitter", "active"))
                .isEqualTo("Dear Mr Pitter, Your current status is active.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, I tried it too, it works fine for $$ only but does not support {{}}.

Comment: You should make that clear in your question. In addition you should include what you've tried so far (not just as a comment)

Comment: My Code:  StringTemplate st = new StringTemplate("Dear Mr {{person_name}}, Your current status is {{current_status}}.");
        st.setAttribute("person_name","Pitter");
        st.setAttribute("current_status","active");
        log.info("StringTemplate: "+ st.toString());                                                 Output: Dear Mr {{person_name}}, Your current status is {{current_status}}.

Comment: Updated answer to "work" with `{{` and `}}`, by replacing them all with a `$`